# Looping through function until condition is met

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to build a php function that checks if a certain url exists in the database:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM taskProposals WHERE url='$string'";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    $quantity = 0;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) { 
        $quantity++; 
    }
    if ($quantity>0) {
        $string = $string.$quantity;
    }

    return $string;
```

The problem with the way I have structured this code is that it will only work the first time that an identical $string is found. Once I change the url by adding `$quantity` to the end, I need to check it again to make sure that new url doesn't exist. Basically, I need to loop through this checking function until I have a totally unique url. After a lot of trial and error, I can't figure out how to set this up.

Comment: Do you use `mysql_real_escape_string` before passing `$string` in your query? Also note that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated (see the [red box](http://php.net/mysql_query)).

Comment: Yes everything is sanitized before it gets this far. I am also aware of the deprecated mysql situation - unfortunately, I don't get to make the call to upgrade to the new api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very inefficient. You drive to the store, buy all items of a particular type, load them into your car, drive home, count how many you bought, then throw them all away. Why not something more like:

```
$sql = "SELECT count(*) AS cnt FROM taskProposals WHERE url='$string';"
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$quantity = $row['cnt'];
```

Don't force the db to fetch data you're simply going to ignore anyways.

Comment: I don't think this solves my problem. I am trying to find a totally unique URL. There may be other URLs on the table that have the name someTask1. I need to avoid duplicating those. So simply counting the number of existing matches to the first input wont find subsequent matches where a quantity number has been added to the end, it will only find the very first match.

Comment: you shouldn't be using `$string.$quantity` anyways. you're counting NUMBERS. **ADD** them. otherwise you'll end up with some ugly url like `....0123456789101112131415` instead, for your first 16 projects.

Comment: Mark, I get that you think I am idiot. I don't care about the ascetics of the url - thats not the problem I am trying to solve. I am simply trying to find logic that will allow me to loop until a certain condition is met.

Comment: so use a `do {} while ()` loop. fetch a count. if it's > 0, then increment a number at the end of the url. then check again. keep repeating until you get a 0 count. but I'd seriously suggest you just store that number as a seperate field in the db, so you just have to `select max(quantity) where url='$string'`. one **SINGLE** query, and you can combine the number and url string together later.